# How should this boost-asio UDP broadcast code work with localhost only?

Tags: c++, networking, boost-asio

The server example for the boost-asio timeouts has 3 command line parameters. I need to know what the 2nd and 3rd  are and how to test the server (where `Usage: server <listen_port> <bcast_address> <bcast_port>`). It says they are the broadcast port and address but if I test this on a single machine as the localhost (e.g. 127.0.0.1) then what happens?

Heres the code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/deadline_timer.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/io_service.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/tcp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/ip/udp.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/read_until.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/streambuf.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/write.hpp>

using boost::asio::deadline_timer;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::asio::ip::udp;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class subscriber
{
public:
  virtual ~subscriber() {}
  virtual void deliver(const std::string& msg) = 0;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<subscriber> subscriber_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class channel
{
public:
  void join(subscriber_ptr subscriber)
  {
    subscribers_.insert(subscriber);
  }

  void leave(subscriber_ptr subscriber)
  {
    subscribers_.erase(subscriber);
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    std::for_each(subscribers_.begin(), subscribers_.end(),
        boost::bind(&subscriber::deliver, _1, boost::ref(msg)));
  }

private:
  std::set<subscriber_ptr> subscribers_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

//
// This class manages socket timeouts by applying the concept of a deadline.
// Some asynchronous operations are given deadlines by which they must complete.
// Deadlines are enforced by two "actors" that persist for the lifetime of the
// session object, one for input and one for output:
//
//  +----------------+                     +----------------+
//  |                |                     |                |
//  | check_deadline |<---+                | check_deadline |<---+
//  |                |    | async_wait()   |                |    | async_wait()
//  +----------------+    |  on input      +----------------+    |  on output
//              |         |  deadline                  |         |  deadline
//              +---------+                            +---------+
//
// If either deadline actor determines that the corresponding deadline has
// expired, the socket is closed and any outstanding operations are cancelled.
//
// The input actor reads messages from the socket, where messages are delimited
// by the newline character:
//
//  +------------+
//  |            |
//  | start_read |<---+
//  |            |    |
//  +------------+    |
//          |         |
//  async_- |    +-------------+
//   read_- |    |             |
//  until() +--->| handle_read |
//               |             |
//               +-------------+
//
// The deadline for receiving a complete message is 30 seconds. If a non-empty
// message is received, it is delivered to all subscribers. If a heartbeat (a
// message that consists of a single newline character) is received, a heartbeat
// is enqueued for the client, provided there are no other messages waiting to
// be sent.
//
// The output actor is responsible for sending messages to the client:
//
//  +--------------+
//  |              |<---------------------+
//  | await_output |                      |
//  |              |<---+                 |
//  +--------------+    |                 |
//      |      |        | async_wait()    |
//      |      +--------+                 |
//      V                                 |
//  +-------------+               +--------------+
//  |             | async_write() |              |
//  | start_write |-------------->| handle_write |
//  |             |               |              |
//  +-------------+               +--------------+
//
// The output actor first waits for an output message to be enqueued. It does
// this by using a deadline_timer as an asynchronous condition variable. The
// deadline_timer will be signalled whenever the output queue is non-empty.
//
// Once a message is available, it is sent to the client. The deadline for
// sending a complete message is 30 seconds. After the message is successfully
// sent, the output actor again waits for the output queue to become non-empty.
//
class tcp_session
  : public subscriber,
    public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_session>
{
public:
  tcp_session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, channel& ch)
    : channel_(ch),
      socket_(io_service),
      input_deadline_(io_service),
      non_empty_output_queue_(io_service),
      output_deadline_(io_service)
  {
    input_deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
    output_deadline_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);

    // The non_empty_output_queue_ deadline_timer is set to pos_infin whenever
    // the output queue is empty. This ensures that the output actor stays
    // asleep until a message is put into the queue.
    non_empty_output_queue_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  // Called by the server object to initiate the four actors.
  void start()
  {
    channel_.join(shared_from_this());

    start_read();

    input_deadline_.async_wait(
        boost::bind(&tcp_session::check_deadline,
        shared_from_this(), &input_deadline_));

    await_output();

    output_deadline_.async_wait(
        boost::bind(&tcp_session::check_deadline,
        shared_from_this(), &output_deadline_));
  }

private:
  void stop()
  {
    channel_.leave(shared_from_this());

    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    socket_.close(ignored_ec);
    input_deadline_.cancel();
    non_empty_output_queue_.cancel();
    output_deadline_.cancel();
  }

  bool stopped() const
  {
    return !socket_.is_open();
  }

  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    output_queue_.push_back(msg + "\n");

    // Signal that the output queue contains messages. Modifying the expiry
    // will wake the output actor, if it is waiting on the timer.
    non_empty_output_queue_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::neg_infin);
  }

  void start_read()
  {
    // Set a deadline for the read operation.
    input_deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(30));

    // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited message.
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket_, input_buffer_, '\n',
        boost::bind(&tcp_session::handle_read, shared_from_this(), _1));
  }

  void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (stopped())
      return;

    if (!ec)
    {
      // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
      std::string msg;
      std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
      std::getline(is, msg);

      if (!msg.empty())
      {
        channel_.deliver(msg);
      }
      else
      {
        // We received a heartbeat message from the client. If there's nothing
        // else being sent or ready to be sent, send a heartbeat right back.
        if (output_queue_.empty())
        {
          output_queue_.push_back("\n");

          // Signal that the output queue contains messages. Modifying the
          // expiry will wake the output actor, if it is waiting on the timer.
          non_empty_output_queue_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::neg_infin);
        }
      }

      start_read();
    }
    else
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  void await_output()
  {
    if (stopped())
      return;

    if (output_queue_.empty())
    {
      // There are no messages that are ready to be sent. The actor goes to
      // sleep by waiting on the non_empty_output_queue_ timer. When a new
      // message is added, the timer will be modified and the actor will wake.
      non_empty_output_queue_.expires_at(boost::posix_time::pos_infin);
      non_empty_output_queue_.async_wait(
          boost::bind(&tcp_session::await_output, shared_from_this()));
    }
    else
    {
      start_write();
    }
  }

  void start_write()
  {
    // Set a deadline for the write operation.
    output_deadline_.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(30));

    // Start an asynchronous operation to send a message.
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
        boost::asio::buffer(output_queue_.front()),
        boost::bind(&tcp_session::handle_write, shared_from_this(), _1));
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (stopped())
      return;

    if (!ec)
    {
      output_queue_.pop_front();

      await_output();
    }
    else
    {
      stop();
    }
  }

  void check_deadline(deadline_timer* deadline)
  {
    if (stopped())
      return;

    // Check whether the deadline has passed. We compare the deadline against
    // the current time since a new asynchronous operation may have moved the
    // deadline before this actor had a chance to run.
    if (deadline->expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())
    {
      // The deadline has passed. Stop the session. The other actors will
      // terminate as soon as possible.
      stop();
    }
    else
    {
      // Put the actor back to sleep.
      deadline->async_wait(
          boost::bind(&tcp_session::check_deadline,
          shared_from_this(), deadline));
    }
  }

  channel& channel_;
  tcp::socket socket_;
  boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer_;
  deadline_timer input_deadline_;
  std::deque<std::string> output_queue_;
  deadline_timer non_empty_output_queue_;
  deadline_timer output_deadline_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_session> tcp_session_ptr;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class udp_broadcaster
  : public subscriber
{
public:
  udp_broadcaster(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const udp::endpoint& broadcast_endpoint)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
    socket_.connect(broadcast_endpoint);
  }

private:
  void deliver(const std::string& msg)
  {
    boost::system::error_code ignored_ec;
    socket_.send(boost::asio::buffer(msg), 0, ignored_ec);
  }

  udp::socket socket_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
      const tcp::endpoint& listen_endpoint,
      const udp::endpoint& broadcast_endpoint)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, listen_endpoint)
  {
    subscriber_ptr bc(new udp_broadcaster(io_service_, broadcast_endpoint));
    channel_.join(bc);

    start_accept();
  }

  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_session_ptr new_session(new tcp_session(io_service_, channel_));

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session, _1));
  }

  void handle_accept(tcp_session_ptr session,
      const boost::system::error_code& ec)
  {
    if (!ec)
    {
      session->start();
    }

    start_accept();
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
  channel channel_;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    using namespace std; // For atoi.

    if (argc != 4)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: server <listen_port> <bcast_address> <bcast_port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::endpoint listen_endpoint(tcp::v4(), atoi(argv[1]));

    udp::endpoint broadcast_endpoint(
        boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(argv[2]), atoi(argv[3]));

    server s(io_service, listen_endpoint, broadcast_endpoint);

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Asio's [Timeout server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/server.cpp) example does the following:

- Functions as a TCP Server, listening to `listen_port`, the first command line argument.
- Enforces input and output deadlines for TCP Clients.  If a deadline expires, then the server will close the connection.
- When a TCP client sends a message, the server will send the same message to each connected client and to the UDP endpoint specified by `bcast_address` and `bcast_port`, the second and third command line arguments.
- The Server only sends data to the UDP socket.  The Server does not read data from the UDP socket.

Despite the naming conventions used in the code, it does not perform UDP Broadcast.  That functionality is enabled via the [`socket_base::broadcast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/socket_base/broadcast.html) socket option.

A connection diagram of the program could be represented as follows:

```
.--------------.    listen_port     .----------------.                  
|              |<---TCP--o )---+--->|  TCP Client A  |                       
|              |               |    '----------------'                        
|    Boost     |               |    .----------------.   
|    Asio      |               `--->|  TCP Client B  |     
|    Server    |                    '----------------'                      
|              | bcast_address:
|              | bcast_port         .----------------.
|              |----UDP--( o------->|  UDP Listener  |
'--------------'                    '----------------'
```

- Boost Asio Server 'connects' to UDP Listener.  The UDP Listener resides on `bcast_address` and listens to port `bcast_port`.
- Bost.Asio Server accepts TCP connections on port `listen_port`.
- The Server can write data to all connections.  However, the Server will only read data from TCP Clients.

For example, if TCP Client A writes "hello", then Server will send "hello" to TCP Client A, TCP Client B, and UDP Listener.  However, if UDP Listener writes "goodbye", then no one will receive it.

---

Here are a few terminals running the Timeout server example using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat).

Start the Server, listening to TCP port 12345 and sending messages to UDP 127.0.0.1 on port 54321.

#### Setup

```
$ ./a.out 12345 127.0.0.1 54321
```

UDP Listener (will listen to UDP on port 54321):

```
$ nc -l -u 54321
```

Start TCP Client A:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 12345
```

Start TCP Client B:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 12345
```

#### Send message

Send "hello" from TCP Client A:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 12345
helloEnter
hello
```

TCP Client B received message:

```
$ nc 127.0.0.1 12345
hello
```

As well as the UDP Listener:

```
$ nc -l -u 54321
hello
```